# No network on Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Ubuntu ARM64

Tags: networking, 18.04, hardware, raspberrypi, arm64

I'm trying to follow the instruction https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi to install Ubuntu ARM64 on my Raspberry Pi 3B+.

The ISO file I chose is Ubuntu Server 18.04 ARM64 (not mini), written to a USB stick.

In installation procedure, it says:
No network interfaces detected

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Update: If I choose to install without network, it will failed later: grub cannot be installed. It seems that ARM64 release of ubuntu server 18.04 is not ready for RPi3B+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will download the generic arm64 server iso and convert it to use the raspi2 kernel - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvHY_kl4hMB4gQXOBm-XGx8sp457

Once run, copy all the files in the server-raspi2 folder to a usb fat formatted drive.  Make sure you copy the hidden '.disk' folder.

The installer has a largish initramfs so there is longer than usual pause at the pi rainbow screen.  The installer also pauses for a long time when it searches for the cdrom.  If you select the 'erase disk and install' option then the installation should work.

Comment: Your script should check whether 7z is installed before downloading iso... lol

Comment: Something's wrong: No USB keyboard supported in my 3b+ while installing. No way to install...

Comment: That's  annoying.  You'll either have to add the kernel modules to the initramfs, or preseed the locale/keyboard questions via cmdline.txt so that you get to the stage where modules are loaded from the cdrom.  If the cdrom fails to detect then you'll definitely have to go the initramfs route.

Comment: 7z is pretty standard.  What are you using?

Comment: This standardized USB keyboard is working well with lots of systems. Actually, this is the 1st time I found it cannot work. How to add keyboard support to your installation media?

Comment: I'm guessing it is a branded keyboard.  These apparently often have their own kernel modules.  You should be able to get a working keyboard if you edit cmdline.txt and add before the '---' hid.ignore_special_drivers=1

Comment: I'll also update the script to copy the kernel modules to the initrd.gz instead of being inserted by pi_early_command

Comment: It's an IBM (lenovo) style keyboard with the red point in the middle lol. I'll test it next Monday and leave feedback. Thanks for your updates.

Comment: Tested, the USB stick prepared by your new script WON'T BOOT. Only black screen displayed. No green light on board either.

Comment: I tried to put those files created by ubuntu wiki to USB stick (without kernel8), waited several minutes, it seemed to halt in rainbow mode. If kernel8 is placed, it start to PXE mode with a text saying partition 1 error. The USB stick created by previous version script can boot into setup at least...

Comment: Sounds to me like the script didn't complete.  This would happen if one of the servers that is downloads from is down.  Raspberrypi.org is currently down, my guess is that it was too when you ran the script.

Comment: I have removed all the scripts.  They take too long for me to test.  There is a problem with the latest one which you have not hit.  The first one should work with the adjustment to cmdline.txt that I wrote above.

Comment: But it's not kept in my hdd...

Comment: I'm trying to use your 2nd version script to build it again. It seems to be finished without downloading problem now. Trying installing.

Comment: Installed. Works well so far. Trying apt upgrade.

Comment: Failed in apt upgrade: mv: failed to preserver ownership for '//boot/firmware/bcm....dtb' and //boot/firmware/initrd.img': Operation not permitted    while upgrading vmlinuz (flash-kernel)

running apt upgrade again reports nothing to be upgraded.

Comment: something weird on NIC dhcp client: it reports a very long unique ID to DCHP server as well as the short MAC address. No matter which one is reserved, it wants to use another one. Have to reserve both.

Comment: any idea about the error in flash-kernel? because the root partition is the FAT one?

Comment: One more problem: if disconnect link from eth0 and reconnect it back, it will use DHCP instead of reading from interfaces file, which specified a static IP address. And, if-up.d script will not be running either.

Answer (score 1):

The generic arm64 kernel in 18.04 doesn't have a dtb file for the 3B+ so I'm not sure what works.  I had hoped it would still work with the dtb file built into uboot.

If you can't get it to work then this https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/aarch64-on-raspberry-pi-2-rev-1-2-3b-3b/16853 should work on the 3B+ because it uses the raspi2 kernel.

Comment: i'm using the one built for 3B. The name of the file for 3B is only including the CPU brand and number, that may confused me.

Comment: BTW, could you explain what's the different between raspi2 kernel and the one in ARM64 official release?

Comment: It should boot without a dtb file.  Remove it and see what happens.  If you still don't have network then you could try insmod'ing the correct module.

Comment: The raspi2 kernel is Ubuntu's version of the 'downstream' kernel from the raspberry pi foundation.  You can boot it without grub2.  The generic arm64 is the upstream kernel.  There are a few differences in the modules used, and the dtb file names.

Comment: without dtb file, it can boot, but still with lacking of nic.

Comment: I tried to boot from the image provided by your link. It seems that shipped with Ubuntu, not Ubuntu Server. I'll try more with Ubuntu Server installation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It might be easier to start with the above xubuntu link, remove all the xubuntu packages and add any server packages you need.

Comment: When I use ubuntu-mate on RPi, I did the similar things before, and it's not a good ending...

Answer (score 0):

I think the 3B+ uses the lan78xx.ko module.  Check if you have that module in the debian installer.  If you don't then you can extract it from the kernel deb, copy it to the 'cdrom' and insmod it.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem related to installer. When booting from u-boot, the 1st line displayed is no ethernet found. I also tested copying 3b+ deb file from the RASPBIAN into u-boot partition. The problem is the same.

Comment: I put the lan78xx.ko to usb stick at boot, once. But now no matter I attach this usb or not, the boot process is blocked in lan78xx_eth Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete. And nothing changed in SD either.... What's wrong here.

Comment: I still have no way to pass the driver right to installer. I use dd to write iso to usb stick (if only file copy, it wont start up). And the shell of the installer dont let me mount any partition --- Invalid argument

Comment: You should be able to mount a partition.  I've done it before now.  I can't remember doing anything special, but that might be my mind playing tricks!  Re: copy vs dd....copying would be beneficial here.  Did you copy the hidden ".disk" folder?

Comment: Yes, I did copy all files including all hidden. Nvm, installing process will fail later for grub error. I think I have to install xubuntu and then remove all desktop components.

Comment: Grub2 fails to install on the 3B too.  It's due to a lack of nvram on the pi.  I've added a bit to the wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Booting_and_installation about this with some pointers on how to overcome it.  I appreciate the instructions are not the best.  Last time I tried there was some other problem with grub2, although I can't remember the details at the moment (corrupt screen maybe?).  I just installed the raspi2 kernel and forgot about grub2.

Comment: I read your updated step but dont know how to do it. After setup failed, I select "Execute a shell" from setup menu, but it doesn't contain grub-install file to execute. There is a grub-installer in /target/bin, but it wont accept --no-nvram as an option.

Comment: grub-install is in /target/usr/sbin, but when I call it, it says /bin/sh: grub-install: not found.

Comment: If I use chroot to change to /target, grub-install failed with cannot find EFI directory.

Comment: Top marks for perseverance!  I've had another go at the wiki.  See if that makes any sense?  If not, and to save any more of your time, instructions to remove the xubuntu-desktop are here https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/aarch64-on-raspberry-pi-2-rev-1-2-3b-3b/16853/4?u=stillwinter

Comment: lol, I dont need the working instance to be prepared asap. So I'd love to dig it through before I turn to raspi2 kernel, which seems to be boring...

Comment: my sd card contains: primary partition in FAT for firmware, logical partition in ext4 for target. my usb stick is written from iso. In grub>, the return of "ls" is "(memdisk) (hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos5) (hd1,msdos1). after I set root=(hd0, msdos2), linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2 returns error: file '/boot/vmlinuz' not found.

Comment: if i use hd1,msdos5+/dev/sdb5, there are 4 errors: /boot/grub/arm64-efi/zfs.mod sfs.mod nilfs2.mod minix.mod not found.

Comment: hd1,msdos5+/dev/sda2: alloc magic is broken at 0x39d96050: 0 Aborted.

Comment: You want hd1,msdos5 with /dev/mmcblk0p5

Comment: hmm, OK, I'll test it next Thursday. Enjoying holidays oversea right now lol

Comment: The release with xubuntu included, is not stable at all. After removing desktop, the apt upgrade processing failed with flash-kernel. And after a reboot, system go into a non-network environment, with no ifconfig either. Have to reinstall from scratch.

Comment: Tested: xubuntu release is not suitable for using without xubuntu-desktop, due to upgrading process will fail with flash-kernel processing, always. Still need to dig into this pure-installation.

Comment: Now I boot into the installed system, but still cannot install grub. When running grub-install, the error is: grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.

Comment: And, there are 2 problems notified: the green led on the device won't work, and the device cannot reboot/shutdown -- system halt in shutting down processing.

Comment: grub installed. need to mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 to /boot/efi manually.

Comment: network support is built in. all I need to do is setup an IP address of the eth0.

Comment: after apt upgrade (dtb file provided to flash-kernel), the NIC is down. And the 2 problems I mentioned above are still.

Answer (score 0):

Argh, sorry about the answer spam.  Different computers, different logins apparently and I can't add a comment.  You may need the microchip.ko module which is the corresponding PHY driver.

Comment: From http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002552A.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem in 18.04 server armhf, not identical configuration, was resolved by edit of netplan setup to define static eth0 ip defs.